# Create a deb package from difference between two images

Tags: debian, ubuntu, rsync, dpkg

I am maintaining an Ubuntu server image as a development environment with several deployments.

If my base image changes - install a package, modify conf files, etc - I am manually patching the new system, or selectively adding the deb files that I knew I added. It is a little tedious and I've missed some system files a couple times.

Is there away to automate this? It seems like a common scenario but I can't find a solution.

I was thinking something along the lines of taking the output of a rsync comparison and generating a deb install package based off these differences. I don't have any experience with either of these so I'd like to check to see if there is an 'off-the-shelf' solution first.

Comment: It seems like a proper solution would be based off of dpkg --get-selections and modifying state based on diffing file state for anything generated in ~/.app or /etc/ ...  I don't think there's a real solution though.  People are trying to tackle it the other way with service orchestration tools like chef or juju.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're asking for DevStructure's [Blueprint](https://github.com/devstructure/blueprint):

The basic idea is that you can [`blueprint create`](http://devstructure.com/blueprint/blueprint-create.1.html) at any time and inspect the generated blueprints or, and this is the amazing part, their diffs, i.e. the things that differ between two blueprints.  [Among other things](https://github.com/devstructure/blueprint/tree/master/blueprint/backend) it [inspects the installed packages](https://github.com/devstructure/blueprint/blob/master/blueprint/backend/apt.py).

The created blueprints can be [pushed to and pulled from a Blueprint I/O service](http://devstructure.com/blueprint/blueprint-push.1.html).
They can also be rendered in various formats, such as [shell scripts](http://devstructure.com/blueprint/#sh), (aesthetically challenged) [Puppet modules or Chef recipes](http://devstructure.com/blueprint/#puppet-chef), and [Cloudformation templates](http://devstructure.com/blueprint/#cloudformation).

**Edit** This does not render your changes in a `deb` file, but if you really want that, you could create a no-op package that includes the generated shell script in `post-install`.

**Edit2** Note that this doesn't give you any roll-backs (such as un-doing the changes to files when removing the resulting `deb` archive).   I don't believe that it's possible to have bolted-on roll-back abilities (but looking at [NixOS](http://nixos.org/nixos) never hurts).

Comment: this looks very promising thanks, I'll give it a try!